# Vectorfields on Surfaces with MuPAD

Tags: surfaces, computer-algebra-systems, vector-fields

i am working with MuPAD. I can make vectorfields in 3D and also Surfaces in 3D via *plot::VectorField3D* and *plot::Surface*.

But now i want to draw a vectorfield **ON** a surface. If $X$ is a vectorfield and $\sigma$ a parametization of a surface $S$ then we can have a look to $X\circ\sigma$. This gives a vectorfield on $S$. But this can not be done with MuPAD, true?

Can someone help me with this problem or can someone explain how to draw such a vectorfield i am searching for?!

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to try to ask this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Search *bunch* and read the associated code in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14202/how-do-i-plot-the-unit-normal-field-for-a-surface) (the normal vector field can be replaced by any one).

Does a command **arrow** exist in MuPad (as in Mathematica) ?